# Render Graphics3D over Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, rendering

I'm using `Show` to merge `Graphics3D` with different 3D Plots. For example:

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{
   {PointSize@0.05, Point[{0, 0, 0}]},
   {Thick, Arrow@{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}},
   {Text[Style["x=-0.5, y=0, z=-0.2", Medium, Bold], {-0.5, 0, -0.2}]}
  }],
 RevolutionPlot3D[{t, 0}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None],
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False
]
```

[image]

However, as seen in the image, graphics primitives get partially overdrawn by 3d plot. So how can one enforce mathematica to render Graphics3D over any other 3D plots?

[image]

Comment: Would `Sphere[]` and `Tube[]` be suitable? `Show[Graphics3D[{Black, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/20], Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}, 1/50]]}], RevolutionPlot3D[{t, 0}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None], Boxed -> False]`

Comment: Well, first of all I have a lot of other complicated combinations of plots and graphics, the case above is just a simplified example. Second - even if i replace them with sphere and tube - they are still not being rendered above the plot.

Comment: It's a 3D model: Objects intersect or lie in between things and the view point.  I'm not sure what you expect.  You could try `Overlay`, if that's what you're after, but that will mess up rotation.

Comment: You want the point rendered on top of the surface?  Or on both sides of the surface?

Comment: On top. As well as Arrow and other primitives.

Comment: `Overlay` seems to be achiving the effect, but it indeed messes up the overall view.

Comment: `Text[]` is a different kettle of fish from other primitives; it is always guaranteed to be overlaid over a plot.

Comment: @J.M.  Axes, too.  It would be nice to have a rendering directive that would overlay primitives like `Text` is done.

Comment: Have you tried using `Opacity` ( `PlotStyle->Opacity[.5]` in `RevolutionPlot3D` ) ?

Comment: @george2079, I did and it is not the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{{PointSize@0.05, Point[{0, 0, 0}]}, {Thick, 
     Arrow@{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}}}];
g2 = RevolutionPlot3D[{t, 0}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None];
plotRange = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
Graphics3D[{Translate[g1[[1]], {0, 0, 0.08}], g2[[1]]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> plotRange]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice trick ;) However it won't work in my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea.  Given that a comment indicated that the use-case is "complicated", I'm not sure it suffices.  You can use `Texture` to apply graphics/images to one or both sides of a surface:

Both sides:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{t, 0}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Texture[Graphics[{{PointSize@0.03, Point[{0, 0}]}, {Thick, 
      Arrow@{{0, 0}, {-1, 0}}}}, PlotRange -> 1]],
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False
 ]
```

Just the "top" (as defined by `RevolutionPlot` and `FaceForm`):

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{t, 0}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  FaceForm[Texture[
    Graphics[{{PointSize@0.03, Point[{0, 0}]}, {Thick, 
       Arrow@{{0, 0}, {-1, 0}}}}, PlotRange -> 1]], White],
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False
 ]
```

Comment: Interesting idea. However flattening graphics onto surface is indeed not a desirable effect.